# How to install Perl packages automatically in FreeBSD using a Perl script without any prompt?

Tags: perl, automation, package, freebsd, cpan

I want to install Perl packages automatically using a Perl script. The code I am using is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use CPAN;
eval "use JSON" 
    or do {
    CPAN::install("JSON");
};
eval "use Net::Address::IP::Local" 
    or do { 

    CPAN::install("Net::Address::IP::Local");
};
eval "use Net::OpenSSH" 
    or do { 

    CPAN::install("Net::OpenSSH");
};
eval "use Net::SCP::Expect" 
    or do { 

    CPAN::install("Net::SCP::Expect");
};
```

During the script runs, it asks for prompt like yes or no, passwords, etc. How to handle these prompt automatically? I have to deploy it on many servers so I had to automate it.

Comment: Are you sure all the users will have cpan configured in a way it will install the modules? Also, after installing a module, you still need to [use](http://p3rl.org/use) it again.

Comment: IIRC there was an environment variable you could set to skip interactive prompts, at least in ExtUtils::MakeMaker based installers. That said, what you're trying to do here is a bad idea in my opinion. *Edit: It was `PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1`.*

Comment: @melpomene Can you please help me out for ExtUtils::MakeMaker with a code snipet........and also are you sure that we need not  not to install this module also.

Comment: @choroba can you provide me another way to install these without cpan

Comment: I find your question baffling. It makes me think you have no idea what you're doing and should probably not try to write this kind of code.

Comment: @melpomene I just want to install these modules automatically before my actual script runs. Can you define me another way

Comment: @DeeptanshuGoel Yes, don't do that. Make installation of prerequisites a separate step; don't try to do it implicitly and at runtime.

Comment: I have to deploy my script on 400+ servers then it would be a pain to install these modules separately

Comment: @melpomene Or we can make a separate script to install these modules first

Comment: Wait, this is about deployment? That would be vital information to include in the question. And you're the admin on those servers and (presumably) know how perl is set up on each one of them? What does your current deployment process look like?

Comment: these servers are using freeBSD OS also

Comment: @melpomene I am having access to all these servers but my teammate has to deploy it, Earlier he was deploying by installing these modules manually but that was very time taking then he asks to automate the installation also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for this that when there is a prompt in between installation of any package either it is automated or manual the prompt got timed out automatically after 15secs, and further installation continues as usual. and also we can give yes in pipe (`|`) if there is prompt for "yes" only.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the [FreeBSD Ports Collection](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html)?

### Use [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pkg) if you just want the defaults

It looks like it could be simplified to just installing a couple of precompiled packages:

```
pkg install -y p5-JSON p5-Net-Address-IPv4-Local p5-Net-OpenSSH p5-Net-SCP-Expect
```

### Use [ports(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ports) if you want more  control over the software you install

If you want to configure those packages (like turning on additional features, disabling documentation installation and so on) then you can just build them yourself from ports:

```
cd /usr/ports/converters/p5-JSON && make install
cd /usr/ports/net/p5-Net-Address-IPv4-Local && make install
cd /usr/ports/net/p5-Net-OpenSSH && make install
cd /usr/ports/net/p5-Net-SCP-Expect && make install
```

See [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html) for more details (like instructions on getting a copy of the ports tree on your machine).

If you just want the defaults then you may pass `BATCH=YES` to the make like this: `make BATCH=YES install`.

If you need any additional packages or you have to tune the existing one beyond what's offered in official ports then you may just get yourself a [copy of the ports tree](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports) and and your own ports/modify existing ones to your liking. See the [Porter's Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/porters-handbook/book.html) for more details.

#### Use existing tools to manage ports efficiently

Ports are generally a great way to manage packages on your system. The framework is easy to use and modify. You may also be interested in looking at the [available ports management tools](https://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/).

Comment: My server is not having /use/ports directory in it and  I have run this pkg install -y p5-JSON p5-Net-Address-IPv4-Local p5-Net-OpenSSH p5-Net-SCP-Expect but when I am running the script it is again asking for packages

Comment: @DeeptanshuGoel You've got to install /usr/ports yourself. See [the handbook chapter about ports](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html). Also, [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) has to be bootstrapped using [pkg(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html). Does it help?

Comment: Didnt got any error but not clear with the concept of ports

Comment: @DeeptanshuGoel Have you read the chapter about ports? https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html

Comment: It seems that my server is not having any configuration files needed by `postsnap` because when I am running this command `portsnap fetch` the output is  `SERVERNAME must be given via command line or configuration file`